# screen sharing - how to access vnc:// address

Tags: vnc, 18.04

I just activated screen sharing feature and got this info:[image]
to view or control you screen by connecting to vnc://mycomputer.
my question is that how can I access this address - which software accept this url?

Answer (score 0):

Remmina is the client software by default - which can handle such address (without vnc://) by selecting vnc protocol in the address bar.